# Javascript way to disable other script tags from executing?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use JavaScript to "remove" a script tag from the DOM BEFORE the script tag gets a chance to execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, javascript can only manipulate parts of the DOM that are loaded already.

Comment: Though, if you had a switch/boolean on those script tags that had to be set by the initial javascript call, that could work.  You just won't be able to remove the tags until after they're loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that [in Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/examples/) with user JavaScript. Here's and example from my UserJS:

```
window.opera.addEventListener('BeforeScript',function (e)
{
// src filter
    var patt1=/collapse|sibnet|upload|progress|krscat|anet|textarea/gi;
// text filter
    var patt2=/saturn-plus|tracker_krs|krasland/gi;
    if (e.element.src.match(patt1)!=null || e.element.text.match(patt2)!=null) e.element.parentNode.removeChild(e.element);
},false);
```

Answer (score 0):

why can't you remove the tag serverside ? perhaps there is an outbound filter you could use with apache to remove the tags?